# How to pattern match on a GADT in Bigarray?

Tags: ocaml, gadt

How do we pattern match on a GADT?  In this case, I'm having trouble with a GADT of Bigarray.  More specifically, the code

```
let print_layout v = match Bigarray.Genarray.layout v with
    | Bigarray.C_layout -> Printf.printf "C layout\n"
    | Bigarray.Fortran_layout -> Printf.printf "Fortran layout\n"
```

fails to compile with the error message

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type
         Bigarray.fortran_layout Bigarray.layout
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
         Bigarray.c_layout Bigarray.layout
       Type Bigarray.fortran_layout is not compatible with type
         Bigarray.c_layout
```

It's complaining about the `Bigarray.Fortran_layout` case.  If we look at `Bigarray` we see that

```
type c_layout = C_layout_typ
type fortran_layout = Fortran_layout_typ
type 'a layout =
    C_layout : c_layout layout
  | Fortran_layout : fortran_layout layout
```

So, it's a GADT and I'm doing something wrong with the pattern matching.  What's a working version of `print_layout`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With gadts, you often need to add annotations when doing a generic pattern matching (one that should work on all the constructors of a type).

Here is the correct way to do what you want:

```
let print_layout (type t) (v: (_,_,t) Bigarray.Genarray.t) =
  match Bigarray.Genarray.layout v with
  | Bigarray.C_layout -> Printf.printf "C layout\n"
  | Bigarray.Fortran_layout -> Printf.printf "Fortran layout\n"
```

The annotation introduces an abstract type t that will be the layout type. By pattern matching on the layout, you discover which layout type it is actually equal to.

Comment: This syntax is nicer than what I found in my searches :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that returns a string representing a layout:

```
let layout_str : type l. l Bigarray.layout -> string = function
  | Bigarray.C_layout -> "C layout"
  | Bigarray.Fortran_layout -> "Fortran layout"
```

You can use this to define your desired function

```
let print_layout v =
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (layout_str (Bigarray.Genarray.layout v))
```

It works for me:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# #load "bigarray.cma";;
# open Bigarray;;
# let fv = Genarray.create int32 Fortran_layout [| 0; 1; 2 |];;
val fv :
  (int32, Bigarray.int32_elt, Bigarray.fortran_layout) Bigarray.Genarray.t =
  <abstr>
# let cv = Genarray.create int32 C_layout [| 0; 1; 2 |];;
val cv : (int32, Bigarray.int32_elt, Bigarray.c_layout) Bigarray.Genarray.t = 
  <abstr>
# let layout_str : type l. l Bigarray.layout -> string = function
  | Bigarray.C_layout -> "C layout" 
  | Bigarray.Fortran_layout -> "Fortran layout";;
val layout_str : 'l Bigarray.layout -> string = <fun>
# let print_layout v =
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (layout_str (Bigarray.Genarray.layout v));;
val print_layout : ('a, 'b, 'c) Bigarray.Genarray.t -> unit = <fun>
# print_layout fv;;
Fortran layout
- : unit = ()
# print_layout cv;;
C layout
- : unit = ()
#
```